# Module for customer can enter products images and attributes

Tags: magento-1.9

I need a site(embroidery shop),Here they designs cloths according to the customer designs.Customer can enter their embroidery images and some attributes. Then it will display price according to the customers details and customer can place their orders.If there is any 3rd party module have similar to these properties .Suggest please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you one premium module using it, you can achieve your functionality.

[Advance custom option](http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html) you can create dependent custom option as well and create custom option template using it.

May be helpful to you.